# Plot code does not work in R Studio but does in R

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

i am trying to move plot results in to rmarkdown in R studio
the following code fails

````
```{r front_stuff ,echo=FALSE,fig.height=3,fig.width=4}
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(htmlTable)
library(data.table)
library(png)
project_folder<-"C:\\Users\\jciconsult\\SkyDrive\\trial_retail\\"
load(paste0(project_folder,"sa_prov_html.RSave"))
load(paste0(project_folder,"Ontario_plot_save.RSave"))
ls()
```
`r ggdraw(cow_plot1)`
````

Error message is

> Quitting from lines 29-29 (test1.Rmd) 
>   Error in `vapply(x, format_sci_one, character(1L), ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE)` : 
>     values must be length 1,
>    but `FUN(X[[1]])` result is length 2
>   Calls:  ... paste -> hook -> .inline.hook -> format_sci -> vapply
>   Execution halted

If I take the same code and copy it into a clear R session (eliminating the stuf for code blocks), everything works.

What I am trying to do is get a document that can convert to word.  I am using the knit HTML option because that is needed to get my htmlTable output to work.
I want something that I can cut and paste into word for final formatting,

Comment: have you tried adding the ggdraw in a code chunk rather than as inline code?

Comment: Also, you could try `library(knitr) ; opts_knit$set(root.dir = project_folder) ; load("sa_prov_html.RSave") ; load("Ontario_plot_save.RSave")` instead of your two `load()`

Comment: Scoa's suggestion of using a code chunk solved the problem nicely. Thanks a lot.  I will also try your knitr suggestion,

Answer (score 2):

The plot cannot be drawn because it is inline code. Try using a code chunk instead:

````
```{r}
ggdraw(cow_plot1)
```
````

Also, the proper way to set a working directory with knitr (which seems to be what you want to achieve) is with the knitr option `root.dir`:

```
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(root.dir = project_folder)
load("sa_prov_html.RSave")
load("Ontario_plot_save.RSave")
```